# GET IG User Insights Facebook Graph API

Tags: r, facebook-graph-api, get

I am trying to GET IG User insights from the Facebook Graph API within R, but unfortunately my script returns an error. I did my best to solve this issue by myself was wasn't able to do so.

I already tried other metrics in my script, but the same issue occurs.

```
access_token <- *[my user access token]*
user_id <- *[my IG user ID]*

insights <- GET("https://graph.facebook.com/",
                path = "me/insights/",
                query =list("metric" = "audience_city", "access_token" = access_token))
content(insights)
```

I expected data about my audience, but received the following error:

```
$error
$error$message
[1] "(#100) The value must be a valid insights metric"

$error$type
[1] "OAuthException"

$error$code
[1] 100

$error$fbtrace_id
[1] "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use the me shorthand here because it'll refer to token not the actual IG account. Replace "me" with the actual IG user/account ID and it'll work fine.